# Is count(distinct col_name) different from counting the rows of a select distinct query?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table with 11 million rows in a MySQL database. One of the columns is a personal id number. People are listed numerous times in the table and I want to know how many unique personal id numbers there are.  And then create a table of those unique numbers.
When I count the distinct personal id numbers from a column, I get a different number than when I insert them directly into a table. For example:

```
select count(distinct person_key) from big_table;
```

gives me a count of 4,074,890.

Then when I try to create a table with them,

```
insert into new_table select distinct person_key from big_table;
```

it only creates 2,701,875 rows.

(Also, if I use the query: `select count(1) from (select distinct person_key from big_table) temp;` it gives me 2,701,875.)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It can be different but only by 1. As counting `distinct column` will exclude null but counting rows includes it. So not clear what is happening there.

Comment: I also can't think of anything that would cause such a big disparity. The `NULL` issue should actually cause `SELECT DISTINCT` to be 1 *larger* than `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Comment: I suspect there's some corruption in the index for `person_key`, try repairing the table.

Comment: Thank you all.  I didn't have an index for the table. I added an index to person_key (using "alter table") and now all queries result in 2,701,875 rows and counts. I am hoping that this number is correct.  Does anyone have any input as to why I should believe this number now that I added an index? Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

> COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])
>
> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values

MySQL Documentation said that. So I think `person_key` has `NULL` Or repeated values